# Input change event listener doesn't work till i trigger another event in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am facing a strange behaviour in my chrome extension, i have a search  input that filter a list of data showed in the extension, and the search input is binded with change listener that should trigger a function that filters the list any time the input changed.

```
const searchInput = document.getElementById('search-list');


searchInput.addEventListener('change', searchList);

function searchList(e) {
  let showingData;
  showingData= data.filter(item=> 
    item.name.toLowerCase().search(e.target.value.toLowerCase()) !== -1);
  renderList(showingData);
}
```

This should work correctly once changing the input, but this works only after clicking anywhere in the body of the extension or clicking `Enter` button in the keyboard, the function `searchList` is not triggered after changing the input which is a strange behaviour, what can be the reason for that??

Comment: The `change` event is only triggered when you leave the input after modifying it, not while you're typing. Use the `input` event.

Comment: @Barmar thank you you can add your answer so i can accept if you want